# json eval giving an error

Tags: javascript, json

i'm using eval for the below JSON but getting syntax error :Expected ']' message. i'm not getting what i'm missing in it.
my javascript stmt is

```
eval('var jsonResponse = ('+response+')');
```

response contains the following:

```
{iserror:"false",employees:["employee":{"employeeNbr":"SAN1234509","emplType":"SAN","agencyNbr":"","producerNbr":"123456789","remiCode":"SA","agentRate":"SA","typeCode":"I","reasonTxt":"S3","rsnDescription":"null","ymdeff":"20130101","ymdend":"20130101","voidtxt":"V","brokerName":"429610583","brokerNpn":"429610583","ymdtrans":"null","opNbr":"null"},
                            "employee":{"employeeNbr":"SAN1234509","emplType":"SAN","agencyNbr":"xxxxx-C","producerNbr":"1234567890,"remiCode":"SA","agentRate":"SA","typeCode":"I","reasonTxt":"S3","rsnDescription":"null","ymdeff":"20130101","ymdend":"20130101","voidtxt":"","brokerName":"429610583","brokerNpn":"429610583","ymdtrans":"null","opNbr":"null"},
                            "employee":{"employeeNbr":"SAN1234509","emplType":"SAN","agencyNbr":"","producerNbr":"123456789","remiCode":"SA","agentRate":"SA","typeCode":"I","reasonTxt":"S3","rsnDescription":"null","ymdeff":"20130101","ymdend":"20130101","voidtxt":"V","brokerName":"429610583","brokerNpn":"429610583","ymdtrans":"null","opNbr":"null"}]}
```

Comment: [Don't use eval!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21)

Comment: If you look at the syntax highlighting alone, you'll notice, that this is no valid code. In general try to use `JSON.parse()` for such tasks, but your data has to "real" JSON.

Comment: That's not JSON. Quotes would be required around `iserror` to be JSON, for example.

Comment: JSLint hates that object right there...I would go check it out to see all the errors: www.jslint.com

Comment: `,"` should be `",` in the second line at `"producerNbr":"1234567890,"remiCode":` also, don't create/parse JSON yourself use a serializer like @VisioN suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you claim it's JSON, but it's not. Quotes would be required around `iserror` to be JSON, for example.

Specifically,

```
{iserror:"false",employees:[...]}
```

should be

```
{"iserror":"false","employees":[...]}
```

---

But since you actually pass the string to a JavaScript parser (eval), it merely needs to be JavaScript, not JSON. It's not valid JavaScript either, which is why you're getting the error.

You have

```
{
   iserror:"false",
   employees:[
      "employee":{...},
      "employee":{...},
      "employee":{...}
   ]
}
```

The `:` after `"employee"` is wrong. Maybe you meant to use

```
{
   iserror:"false",
   employees:[
      {...},
      {...},
      {...}
   ]
}
```

---

Also, you have

```
"producerNbr":"1234567890,"remiCode":"SA"
```

instead of

```
"producerNbr":"1234567890","remiCode":"SA"
```